# Riesz theorem and $L^p$ norm in expectation

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lp-spaces

I am reading a paper that uses the following fact, which claims to be from the Riesz's theorem:

> For a continuous stochastic process $\{ X_t \}$, let $u_t$ be its density function at each time point $t$. Let $p \geq 1$ and $q$ be its Holder's conjugate. Suppose that there exists a nonnegative function $K(t)$ such that 
>   $$ \big| \mathbb{E} [ f( X_t) ] \big| \leq K(t) \| f \|_p .$$
>   Then
>   $$ \| u_t \| _q \leq K(t).$$

As far as what I know, the Riesz's theorem merely tells us that for a compact Hausdorff space $X$, for any bounded linear functional $\Lambda \in  C(X)$, we can correspond it to a Borel measure $\mu$ through the Lebesgue integral. How does this conclude this result? Or is there an alternative version of this theorem which might be helpful in showing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) points out, there are several  results called Riesz (representation) theorem. A common feature of some of them is that on some spaces, every linear functional is integration against something.  The result that the author uses here is the [representation of linear functionals on $L^q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1020121): they are integrals against $L^p$ functions. More precisely, all that's needed here is the equality case of Hölder's inequality: 
$$
\|u_t\|_q = \sup\left\{\int f u_t : \|f\|_p\le 1\right\}\tag{1}
$$

Since $E[f(X_t)] = \int f(\omega)u_t(\omega)$, the result follows.